# Restrict qualifier on class member pointers

Tags: c++, llvm, strict-aliasing, restrict-qualifier

I've a program like this, where I've to abstract pointers using a class. I'd like the compiler to optimize the unrolled loop in the `main` function below assuming no pointer aliasing. How can I effectively use `__restrict` construct in this scenario? I'm using Clang with RISC-V backend.

```
extern int* getPtr(int n); // Runtime function providing data

class RemotePtr {
  private:
    int* a;

  public:
    RemotePtr(int* a) : a(a) {}

    int& at(int n) {
      return a[n];
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int* A = getPtr(0);
  int* B = getPtr(1);

  RemotePtr a(A);
  RemotePtr b(B);

  // This loop should be compiled assuming no aliasing between 
  // pointers `a.a` and `b.a`
  #pragma unroll 4
  for(int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
    a.at(i) += b.at(i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Following is the classic usecase of `__restrict` and when I compile this, I see `noalias` annotated in the LLVM IR as desired.

```
int* A;
int* B;

void vec_add(int* __restrict a, int* __restrict b, int n) {
  #pragma unroll 4
  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    a[i] += b[i];
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  vec_add(A, B, 4);
  return 0;
}
```

Snip of resulting IR:

```
; Function Attrs: nofree norecurse nounwind
define dso_local void @_Z7vec_addPiS_i(i32* noalias nocapture %a, i32* noalias nocapture readonly %b, i32 %n) local_unnamed_a
ddr #0 {
entry:
  %cmp6 = icmp sgt i32 %n, 0
  br i1 %cmp6, label %for.body.preheader, label %for.cond.cleanup

for.body.preheader:                               ; preds = %entry
  %0 = add nsw i32 %n, -1
  %xtraiter = and i32 %n, 3
```

Finally, changing the line `a.at(i) += b.at(i);` to a lambda function call with restrict seems to work:

```
([&](int& __restrict a, int& __restrict b) {a += b;})(a.at(i), b.at(i));
```

I guess, that gives what I want:

```
; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind
define dso_local i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** nocapture readnone %argv) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %0 = load i32*, i32** @A, align 4, !tbaa !3
  %1 = load i32*, i32** @B, align 4, !tbaa !3
  %2 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4, !tbaa !7, !alias.scope !9, !noalias !12
  %3 = load i32, i32* %0, align 4, !tbaa !7, !alias.scope !12, !noalias !9
```

But I'd want to abstract this in the class and not require user to write a lambda construct to achieve the result for ease of use, as well as to avoid missing this optimization.

Comment: What have you tried? My guess would be to add the `__restrict` to the return type of `at`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks! I added the the compiler I'm using.

Comment: @Phil1970, I tried that, but I see no sign of `noalias` annotation in the IR... added what more I tried to the description.

Comment: As far as I understand __restrict from what I read, your `vec_add` solution would be the proper one. However, it seems that you could an operator `+=` inside `RemotePtr` that would add the for numbers thus allowing an easy syntax for your user. The only thing they would need to be aware is that `a += a` for example would be undefined behavior while without `__restrict` it would double the value. But then you can provide a scalar multiplication operator so they can write `a *= 2` instead.